# writing nested summation in full

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm practising with precalculus exercises and came across this question of double summation. But I couldn't do it like a single sigma notation. Question is, how can I write this formulae in full to see what it does.

$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^2 w_i x_j$$

Answer (score 2):

Handle the inner summation first.
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^2 w_i x_j &= \sum_{i=1}^3 (w_i x_1+w_ix_2)\\
\end{align}
Are you able to do it now?

Comment: not really... even if I can, can't be sure if it is true.

Comment: @PRCube $$= (w_1x_1 + w_1x_2) + (w_2x_1 + w_2x_2) + (w_3x_1 + w_3x_2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation which might be helpful. We start with a simpler example for demonstration. Using the *[distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)* once without sigma notation and once with sigma notation we can write
\begin{align*}
w(x_1+x_2)&=wx_1+wx_2\\
w\sum_{i=1}^2x_i&=\sum_{i=1}^2wx_i
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2w_ix_j&=\sum_{i=1}^3w_i\sum_{j=1}^2x_j\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{i=1}^3w_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^2x_j\right)\\
> &=(w_1+w_2+w_3)(x_1+x_2)
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $w_i$ is not depending on the inner sum, we can factor it out in (1).